# Clean ndb_binlog_index file

Tags: mysql, mysql-cluster

I have a question about one of my ndb clusters. because there are two files too big and I don't know why...

```
ls -la
-rw-rw---- 1 mysql mysql 32827950588 May 25 12:35 ndb_binlog_index.MYD
-rw-rw---- 1 mysql mysql  6493449216 May 25 12:35 ndb_binlog_index.MYI

ls -lah
-rw-rw---- 1 mysql mysql  31G May 25 12:35 ndb_binlog_index.MYD
-rw-rw---- 1 mysql mysql 6.1G May 25 12:35 ndb_binlog_index.MYI
```

How can I reduce the size ?
Do you have any similar experience ? What information is stored ?
MySQL Version: mysql-cluster-gpl-7.2.12-linux2.6-x86_64

Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

These are the binary log files which mysql uses to synchronize the databases across the cluster (Master-slave). This link may be help full to you

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysqlbinlog.html